# Creating a contact view that includes custom profile fields

Tags: contact-view

Struggling with this one so hope the wiser heads on here can help.

I've created some custom fields for my volunteers and created a profile so I can view these

[image]

So running this "advanced search" then displays the list of contacts with the fields I want to be able to see at a glance

[image]

However I cannot work out how to make this a saved search that other users can easily run whenever they want.

Everything I have tried has resulting in losing the extra fields I want to display.

Answer (score 1):

You set the profile in the Civi >> Admin >> Customize data and screens >> Save Preference. This will keep the column same for all contact search result.

Alternatively you can use searchkit to build your own search with columns and filters.

Comment: Sorry Pradeep, I'm not with you there -  Civi >> Admin >> Customize data and screens >> I have, but 'Save Preference', where is that?
I like searchkit but I note the 'Actions' do not include "Send SMS" which is a client requirement on this project!

Comment: Should be `Administer > Customize data and screens > Search Preferences` then look for the 'Default Contact Search Profile'

Comment: This is something I'd attempted but the drop down by "Default Contact Search Profile" does not include the Profile I created (https://prnt.sc/aJ0iXAq832Gv).  How are the profiles chosen to appear in the drop down list at  "Default Contact Search Profile" ? They seem to be a mix of User-defined profiles and Reserved Profiles. 
I have a profile both in User-defined Profiles (where I could access it in Advanced Search) and in Reserved Profiles where it is used when entering the volunteer information on the registration form

Comment: I tried adding the fields I want to display to an existing default profile called "Your Registration Info" and then choosing this in Search Preferences in the Default Contact Search Profile drop down. If found that if I added a field to "Your Registration Info" then the choice of "Your Registration Info" in Default Contact Search Profile disappeared. Why would that be?